# Transfer control over open bounty to other user (or moderator) because I can't award it

Tags: support, bounty

I have two open bounties ([question 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771943/enable-fncursor-arrows-on-lock-login-screen-to-change-volume-and-brightness) and [question 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773860/bidirectionally-synchronize-thunderbird-profiles-pop3-mail-accounts-between-tw)) of 50 points for each, which both end in 3 days.

However, I can't come online within the next week and none of them has an acceptable answer yet. I don't want these 100 points in total to be wasted though.

Can I allow anybody else (either another AU user which I would trust or a moderator) to award these bounties if the questions get another, probably good and working answer? Of course I could give my account credentials away, but can I also just ask for a transfer of the bounty ownership?

Or can I only rely on the automatic awarding of half of the bounty in case any answer receives enough votes?

Comment: Maybe we can simply mass-upvote the answer you want to award.

Comment: @Helio Would that not be targeted up voting? Kind of undermines the vote system if users go there specifically to up vote a certain answer.

Comment: @MarkKirby: Yes, it would be another way of cheating the system. However, I think that SE doesn't support bounty control transfer.

Comment: Another way would be changing the password of your account and send the credentials to a moderator. Once the bounty is assigned, change it again.

Comment: @Helio I think your right, I can't find anything on this anywhere on SE, your second suggestion may work well though :)

Comment: @Helio a score of +2 is enough, IIRC.

Comment: @muru Y,YRC **;-)**

Comment: Can't you manually award another bounty later?

Comment: @anonymous2 Sure, I could do that. But that would still mean my current 100 bounty points are wasted.

Comment: You mean, 24k users think about that?  :)

Comment: @anonymous2 Probably not, but I only have 20.4k ;-)

Comment: Oh...  Gotcha.  Seriously, I didn't realise the 100 bounty points are taken out of your account before they're awarded.

Comment: @anonymous2 - And that is what's keeping me from starting bounty.

Comment: @anonymous2 Yep and if no good answers are given, those points are just lost forever, that is why he cares what happens to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a bounty control transfer.

Moderators can't do it, they can only revoke and return the bounty which requires exceptional circumstances I believe.

There's no way to transfer control as far as I am aware

Comment: Comment as an answer.

Comment: Well... problem solved itself when the bounties simply expired... :-/